# What did Wonder Woman do during World War II?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

In the recent Wonder Woman film, we learn that the first World War was the work of Ares, God of War/Truth.

When Wonder Woman kills Ares, it takes away the desire for war from everyone, resulting in peace.

We then jump forward to what appears to be modern-day France, with the titular hero in her office.

With Ares dead then:

- Did World War II happen?

and, if it did,

- Did Wonder Woman fight in WWII?

Comment: I thought a big part of what Ares was saying was that he wasn’t needed to cause conflict. “They start these
wars on their own.” He was evil, but that didn’t mean he was wrong.

Comment: I agree with Obie on this one - Ares *isn't inputting the desire for war* into anyone. What he reveals to WW is that all he's doing is giving them ideas for bigger and better weapons.

Comment: @Obie When WW kills Ares, the Germans' desire to fight is visibly lessened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Did World War II happen?

There is *some* evidence that **a** World War II happened.

Lex says in *Batman vs. Superman*...

> "You know, dad was born in **East Germany**. He grew up...eating stale crackers. And every other Saturday, he had to march in a parade and waved flowers at tyrants. So I think it was providence that his son, me, would end up with this. "

East Germany only came into being as a **direct result of WWII**.

---

> Did Wonder Woman fight in WWII?

Based *only* on the movies to date (10/2017)...**we don't know**.

It seems likely that, *if she did*, then it was on a very low-key level since no-one recognises her.

The implication of what we know is that Diana slips into the shadows of history and  if indeed she took any action during WWII, Korea or Vietnam etc. it hasn't been public knowledge since no-one is aware of her.

Certainly in *BvS* she says..<sup>*</sup>

> A hundred years ago I walked away from mankind. From a century of horrors. Man made a world where standing together is impossible.

The implication is that she did NOT take part.....but that may get retconned in a later movie.

<sup>* [Hat-tip to this question/answer at SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162395/where-was-diana-during-the-events-of-man-of-steel/162396#162396)</sup>

Answer (score -5):

In the comics, the story happens during WWII.
For evident confusion reason (did I really need to explain it), they moved the story to WWI.

For What will happens during WWII.. well, may be it will be for WonderWoman 2

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read that one of the reasons PJ chose to change the traditional comic WWII story to WWI was to move away from what she sees as an overuse of WWII in media, so I think it's unlikely we will see a WWII film, if PJ is the director/co-writer. It's not that I think it won't be relevant to future stories in either WW or JL, but I think it will probably be background information in any contemporary-setting future film, unless somebody wants to parallel real-life with neo-revival philosophies.