# What was Wonder Woman doing during the events of Man of Steel?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

Wonder Woman makes an appearance in Batman v Superman. During World War I, she is active. She may or may not have been active in events between these two events, like World War II or Cold War.

But why was she not active in fighting General Zod during the events of *Man of Steel*? Why did she not help, while so much was happening?

Comment: Related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81682/what-did-wonder-woman-do-during-world-war-ii

Comment: Related question on SF&F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162395/where-was-diana-during-the-events-of-man-of-steel/162396#162396

Comment: @Paulie_D , I agree with the "related" question. I also agree with the exact "Dupe" on other site where I am not yet a member. I did go through the list of suggestions while typing my question, but this did not pop up. There is no clarity on which question is suitable where; Some questions are suitable on both. What should I do now ? Delete ?

Comment: @ Who-ever-downvoted : Is that because of the Dupe, which I was not aware of ? Or it is badly written ? Or it is off topic here ? What improvements can I make ?

Comment: @Prem unintentional cross-site dupe is fine and this question seems fine to me, tried to answered also.

Answer (score 1):

**What was Wonder Woman doing during the events of Man of Steel?**

We don't know exactly but she just walked away from humanity, as she explained to Bruce in *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice*:

> *BRUCE WAYNE:* They will. And they'll fight. We have to stand together.
>
> *DIANA PRINCE:* A hundred years ago I walked away from mankind. From the century of horrors. Man made a world where standing together is impossible.
>
> *BRUCE WAYNE:* Man is still good. We fight. We kill. We betray one another. But we can rebuild. We can do better. We will. We have to. - [source](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice)

But we later see in prequel *Wonder Woman* that she did participate in World War 1 and the sequel [Wonder Woman 1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman_1984) is set in Cold War time, maybe in this film or later films we will get to know the exact reasons why she skipped WW2 or Zod attack but for now we have to take her words from BvS.

Comment: +1 , & thanks ! Yes, Probably this is the maximum we can know with the contents from available movies. The issue I have is : "walking away" is vague and ambiguous, but it may mean she left and went back to her Island, after WW1. But then, Batman could not have casually contacted her with the picture. Also she was casually flying in the flight among mankind. Implication is that she was still within mankind, though maybe not active, but that inactivity would not make much sense.

Comment: Probably, Directors and Producers of MoS did not know about BvS or WW to worry about the missing WW on MoS. Attempting to rectify that may be like this : If BvS had shown her on the Island and she had been monitoring things and then some Islander had convinced her to go back to mankind , it could make sense.

Comment: @Prem WOnder Woman sequel are taking place before Man of Steel, so many some of them can explain that